# Minimal ROS2 Installation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a repo file available that produces a minimal ROS2 installation similar to ros-base from ROS1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325245/minimal-ros2-installation/) by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repos file is an artifact of our development process from before ROS2 distros existed. You can get what you want using the rosinstall_generator just like you can with ROS 1 distros. e.g.

Release tags:

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --rosdistro dashing ros_base
```

Upstream tags:

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --upstream --rosdistro dashing ros_base
```

Upstream devel branches

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --upstream-devel --rosdistro dashing ros_base
```

For faster checkouts you don't plan to edit you can use the tarballs option.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on 2019-06-10**:
Awesome.  I didn't even think to try the old setup.  Thanks.

**Comment by [mechapancake](https://answers.ros.org/users/51396/mechapancake/) on 2020-02-06**:
Looking for the same thing as OP.  I've been following the ROS 2 build guide here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Linux-Development-Setup/

For a minimal install, I should run `rosinstall_generator` prior to the `colcon build` command, correct?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-06**:
You should replace the wget of the 'ros2.repos' file with the rosinstall_generator command.

**Comment by [nealtanner](https://answers.ros.org/users/65282/nealtanner/) on 2021-01-13**:
How big should the ros_base download be? I tried this with foxy and it downloaded >800 MB of source repos.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-01-14**:
That's a little higher than I'd expect. If you check out the tarballs with just the latest checkout I see 124MB. Dependeing on what packages you're pulling the repositories from you can have a good amount of historical versions included in the default clone of the repositories, especially the release repositories which are not optimized for minimal git clones.